# python; jsonschema, validate that a schema is valid jsonschema

Tags: python, jsonschema

This package can be used to validate that a given instance I matches a schema S: https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/tree/master/jsonschema

I am looking for another package or method to tell whether a given schema S is valid JSON-Schema Draft XXX. Is there a standard way to do this?

One thought is to find a download the schema draft itself like draft 4 (http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#), and then pass that and S into `validate` but I'm wondering if there is a better way to check "this schema is a valid jsonschema".

Answer (score 2):

That's precisely how schemas are validated!  Download the meta-schema (declared in the `$schema` keyword) and validate the schema against the meta-schema.  It's designed to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The API to validate a schema itself is [SomeValidator.check_schema](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#jsonschema.IValidator.check_schema).

Please let me know (by filing an issue) if there's anything in the documentation that would have helped you find it easier!

Comment: yes this would have been helpful, possibly adding an example to the main README would be nice imo =)